# UnknownHostException and ConnectionException being fired by Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

Im using Retrofit with the RxJava adapter set in my Android App. The issue is that I got some reports that in some devices Retrofit is firing `ConnectionException` and in some other devices is firing `UnknownHostException`. This makes pretty difficult to plug other `rx.Observables` using the `onErrorResume()` method. Even worse, the only common parent that both Exceptions share is `IOException` which is pretty generic. There's a way to unify this?

I was only handling the `UnknownHostException` case. But now I also have this `ConnectionException`, and who knows which other exception in some other device.

I could map this two exceptions to a generic custom exception, something like `NoInternetConnectionException`. But, there's more of this exceptions out there?

**UPDATE:**

Currently my Interactors/UseCases are doing things like:

```
mNetworkUserRepository.getUserList()
    .onErrorResule(ObservableUtils.whenExceptionIs(RetrofitError.class), mUserDatabase.getUserList()) //Server side error
    .onErrorResule(ObservableUtils.whenExceptionIs(UnknownHostException.class), mUserDatabase.getUserList()) //No internet
    .onErrorResule(ObservableUtils.whenExceptionIs(ConnectionException.class), mUserDatabase.getUserList()) //ANOTHER EXCEPTION FOR THE SAME THING
    .subscribe(new MySubscriber<List<Users>>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(List<Users> response) {
            callback.showOnUI(response);
        }
    });
```

So basically in Samsung S7 the UnkownHostException is being fired, in another device a Nexus, ConnectionException is being fired. I don't like this, how many other "no internet" exceptions are out there? I though that Retrofit only fired UnknownHostException if I tried to make an http request without internet connection. How can I group this? I don't wanna attach N onResumeErrors for different devices and stuff

Comment: What's the question exactly? are you trying to distinct between different types of errors by exception type? what's the problem using generic exception?

Comment: @yosriz I updated my answer. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Just catch `IOException` and you're set (assuming your `whenExceptionIs` method isn't using class equality).

Comment: @TassosBassoukos Yeah I know, that's actually the workaround that I'm using right now, but I don't like it, because I think that the IOException is too generic. I mean IOException is also fired when something goes wrong reading a file from the storage.

Answer (score 2):

You can't actually know from an exception whether there is no internet, or some other network error occurred along the way, as you encountered, there are many others situations and Exceptions you might get like
`SocketTimeoutException`, `UnknowHostException` or any other network related `Exception` derived from `IOException` (you can see the dozens of derived classes from [IOException](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html)), it may or may not be related to no internet, as network operation can fail in so many phases from different sources, especially when you on mobile network.

So, I think that if you really need 'no internet' behavior you should [check it](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) before the request and act differently ahead.

When you do perform a call, I think there are 2 kinds of failure to consider, `IOException` for any network error happened along the way. (not much to do but retry/use cache whatever your case), and the retrofit error (`HttpException`) that means you got response from Server (no network error) but something wrong with the request itself (there you can have plenty of reasons for error you might act upon - authentication error (token), authorization etc.)

Comment: OK, yeah, as I commented above, right now hooking from IOException is the workaround that I'm using. I'm gonna wait to see if someone comes with a better solution, but I guess that in the end, maybe I will have to go with this.

Comment: @yosriz >>if you really need 'no internet' behavior you should check it before the request<<  
If before there was an internet, but while performing request it's gone, then you see positive behaviour with negative result. So the suggestion is questionable.